# Image preview using views

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I want to Create like [this](http://san-francisco-cupcakes.myshopify.com/collections/chocolate/products/cookies-and-cream) type of Image preview on particular related images. I have image fields with multiple images for a content type, and I would like to obtain this effect.

[image: sample image]

Is there any possibility by creating views? Is there any way to obtain this effect with other ways?

Comment: I am not sure whether we have any modules to bring this effect. But just as a suggestion, you can achieve this using the templates. Render all the images associated with the field, and then use the template and CSS to theme like this.

Comment: +1 for the Oreo's picture. `:)` On a serious side, this is interesting. I would stay away from templates, but that is because I use them just to theme output, not to create output.

Comment: By the way, you should also describe what you tried. We don't accept questions showing a screenshot and asking "How can I achieve this?"

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes i want achieve like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Views Gallerific](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic) You can solve easily.Please follow the steps from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578774)

Answer (score 1):

## Modules You Need:

1. [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
2. [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries)
3. [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)
4. [Cycle JS](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js) : Save this js file to `/sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/` where you have to create 2 directories i.e.  libraries and under that jquery.cycle

Now assuming your content type name is **IMAGE** with two fields

- Title
- Image

[image]

## Add 3 dummy images to your newly created content type IMAGE

Now go to `admin/structure/views/import`

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'slideshow';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Slideshow';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Slideshow';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'slideshow';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['slideshow_type'] = 'views_slideshow_cycle';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['slideshow_skin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['skin_info'] = array(
  'class' => 'default',
  'name' => 'Default',
  'module' => 'views_slideshow',
  'path' => '',
  'stylesheets' => array(),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['enable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_pager_fields';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['views_slideshow_pager_fields_fields'] = array(
  'field_image' => 'field_image',
  'field_image_1' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_controls']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_controls']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_controls_text';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_slide_counter']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_pager_fields';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['views_slideshow_pager_fields_fields'] = array(
  'field_image' => 0,
  'field_image_1' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_controls']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_controls']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_controls_text';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_slide_counter']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['timeout'] = '5000';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['speed'] = '700';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['delay'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['start_paused'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['remember_slide_days'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['items_per_slide'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['wait_for_image_load_timeout'] = '3000';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['cleartype'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['cleartypenobg'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['id'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['field'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  'image_link' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Field: Content: Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['id'] = 'field_image_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['field'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_1']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'image' => 'image',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'slideshow';
```

Simply go to your-site/slideshow and Voilà! Feel free to comment if you got stuck or need my help.